# Google Maps API 3 How to call initialize without putting it in Body onload

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps API and have copied the examples and have ended up with a function called "initialize" that is called from the body onload.

I am using the maps in a few different user controls, which are placed within content place holders, so the body tag is in the master page.

Is there a way of calling initialize directly in the usercontrol rather than having to place an onload on the masterpage?
Ideally I want my user control to be a stand alone control that I can just slot into pages without trying to access the master page body onload.

I have tried calling the Initialize function from my page load of the user control (by adding a start up script), but the map doesn't appear.

Any suggestions?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">/script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.8052184317649, -4.965819906250006);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/GoogleMapsService.asmx/GetPointers",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".loadingData").html("<p>Loading data..</p>");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $(".loadingData").html("");
        },
        cache: true,
        success: mapPoints,
        error: onError
    });
}
function onError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
function mapPoints(response) {

    if (response.d != null) {
        if (response.d.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                plotOnMap(response.d[i].Id, response.d[i].Name,
                    response.d[i].Lat, response.d[i].Long,
                    response.d[i].ShortDesc)

            }
        }

    }
}
```

and on my test master page:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: can you help with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792518/why-didnt-work-my-classic-asp-source-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answer but I finally did it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:(this script you can use in the usercontrol)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($('#map_canvas').length != 0) {
            //google map stuff here
          }
      });
    </script>
```