# Why didn't work my classic asp source code?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

When i run this code, nothing displayed, it shows blank. I checked inspector and network tab..

```
function storevaluestoSession()
{
    var somewhere=map.getCenter()
    map.setCenter(somewhere);
    var somewhere=String(somewhere)
    var nloc=somewhere.search(',');
    var location2=String(somewhere).substring(1,nloc);
    var sw2=String(somewhere);
    var lsw2=sw2.length-1;
    var lsw22=nloc+1;
    var location3=sw2.substring(lsw2,lsw22);
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location2,location3); 

    var lat2=ltrim(location2.toString());
    var lon2=ltrim(location3.toString());
    var CurrentpkFamily=<%=session("pkfamily")%>;

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","sessionhelper.asp?lat="+lat2+"&lon="+lon2+"&CurrentpkFamily="+CurrentpkFamily, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And i am new to asp, can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: Any error at console?

Comment: nothing error,, @Manwal: finally i have to run this code to bring jmap.. please help me.. thanks

Comment: when i see in view source ,only display java script which i had post(last place of my source code link).

Answer (score -1):

The response is in xmlhttp.responseXML. Add

```
  alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
```

before the last } to see server response.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know.. where i can add. I posted just sample.. my full source code is as i provided link.. thanks

Comment: Before line 565. Alternatively, you can go (in web browser) to **sessionhelper.asp?lat=&lon=&CurrentpkFamily=** with some values in lat, lon and CurrentpkFamily to see server response.

Comment: when i run sessionhelper.asp?lat=&lon=&CurrentpkFamily, server not found

Comment: Sorry but I don't know where this file must be... 
(In my last comment there are an error. The line of your code is 1601, not 565)

Comment: still nothing happen.. actually nothing work my code :(

Comment: can you please go through my code, it is right or not? thanks

Comment: You say that no errors are displayed so there is no syntax problems ... but do not know what happens in sessionhelper.asp ...

Comment: actually.. those are totally not working, in this code lots of conditions there..if those conditions are true, then only will work..